# Get position from parent right edge in %

Tags: javascript, position

Given a clientX coordinate, how can I determine how far that point is from the *right* edge of the parent container? I can do left edge correctly with

```
event.target.style.left = (((cX-event.target.parentNode.offsetLeft)) / event.target.parentNode.clientWidth)*100 +"%";
```

but can't seem to figure out the values to compare with, in relation to the right edge.. (edited)

or, actually, how far the right edge of event.target is from the right, since style.right positions from the right edge
 cX is the clientX of a JQuery UI draggable stop callback's event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `getClientBoundingRect()`

```
  function getPosition(e) {
      var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log(rect)
      var x =  Math.abs(e.clientX - rect.right);
      var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
      return {
        x,
        y,
        procent: x / (rect.width / 100)  
      }
   }
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/bogdanm/ocLn138v/

Comment: This seems to give distance from left edge? Which is what I already can do.... I want the distance of the right edge of clientX, from the target's parent element's right edge, in %

Comment: @RandoHinn I forgot to save the changes in fiddle, check again the fiddle (the code I added in this answer still applies)

Comment: How is this affected by the padding on the parent's parent? rect.right seems to be the parent's parent's left edge :/ Said grandparent has padding:4rem;

Comment: tried just using the procent value.. the closer to the right edge I drop the element, the bigger the % gets  (over 100)